# Excessive CPU fan noise due to MS office 2013

Tags: windows-7, cpu, fan, noise, office-2013-preview

My desktop computer was making too much noise.. I guess it was CPU fan because graphic card fan and case fan was normal.
I checked cpu usage in task manager and was so surprised that officestarter2013.exe was using 78% of cpu even though I did not even start office after booting.
After ending that process, noise disappeared. Now I have only normal level of noise.
How could it happen? Is it a kind of virus?
The office suite is office 2013 preview version.

My system is
OS : Windows 7 professional service pack 1 (32-bit)
CPU : core i5-2500 @ 3.3GHz
RAM : 8GB (but 3.24GB usable)
It is HP Small form factor.

Answer (score 3):

Go to options > Advanced > Scroll Down to display settings > untick GPU settings

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Go to options > Advanced > Scroll Down to display settings > check the disable hardware graphics acceleration box

all your problems will be solved tested on Window 7